# Scope of #TempTables limited to an EXEC statement?

Tags: sql-server, exec, temp-tables

By trying this

```
use master
go

select * into #TempTable from sys.all_views 
select * from #TempTable
drop table #TempTable

exec('
select * into #TempTable2 from sys.all_views 
')
/* This will give error: */
select * from #TempTable2
```

I realized that #TempTable2 is not accessible... so using the `select into #TempTable` syntax is used inside an EXEC statement means the table is auto destroyed as the exec statement is completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You can see this with

```
exec('
select * into #TempTable2 from sys.all_views 
select * from tempdb.sys.tables
')
select * from tempdb.sys.tables
```

You can use a `##global` temporary table if you want to be able to access it later. e.g.

```
use master
go
declare @temptablename char(40)

set @temptablename = '[##' + cast(newid() as char(36)) + ']'

exec('
select * into ' + @temptablename + ' from sys.all_views 
')
/* Do some other stuff: */

exec('
select * from ' + @temptablename)
```

Comment: THanks for the NEWID(trick) with this i solve exactly my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a global temp table

```
create table ##TempTable (
    /* Structure goes here */
)

exec('insert into ##TempTable(/*Columns*/) select * from sys.all_views')

select * from ##TempTable
```

(If you do this, and your code might be used by multiple users, then include a SPID column in the temp table, include @@SPID in the select list, and change the final select to filter by SPID = @@SPID)

Comment: There is no need for the insert statement.  If you `select into` a global temp table it will be accessible outside of the `Exec` scope.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct.  The temp table within the `Exec` statement is only accessible within that statement.

If you open two windows in SSMS and create a temp table in one window you won't be able to access it through the other window as it is a different connection.

However, you will be able to access it if you create a global temp table.  Global temp tables are defined with a double ## instead of one.

There is an article [here from SQLTeam](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables) regarding temp tables and also [here from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177399.aspx)

Comment: you mentioned 2 different windows, but my problem is in the same window just after the exec statement. Anyway thanks the answer is clear.